# How to deal with bad data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables that I want to combine.

I have the following query to run:

```
DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS testgiver.smart_curmonth_downs;

CREATE TABLE testgiver.smart_curmonth_downs


SELECT
ldap_karen.uid,
ldap_karen.supemail,
ldap_karen.regionname,
smart_curmonth_downs_raw.username,
smart_curmonth_downs_raw.email,
smart_curmonth_downs_raw.publisher,
smart_curmonth_downs_raw.itemtitle,
smart_items.`Owner`
FROM
smart_curmonth_downs_raw
INNER JOIN ldap_karen ON smart_curmonth_downs_raw.username = ldap_karen.uid
INNER JOIN smart_items ON smart_curmonth_downs_raw.itemtitle = smart_items.Title
```

I want to know how to create the joins while maintaining a one to one relationship at all times with rows in table smart_curmonth_downs_raw.

For instance if there is not a uid in ldap_karen I have issues.  And then the last issue I have found is that our CMS is allowing for duplicate itemtitle.  So if I run my query I am getting a lot more rows because it is creating a row for each itemtitle.  For example would there be a way to only catch the last itemtitle that is in smart_items.  I would just really like to maintain the same number of rows - and I have no control over the integrity issues of the other tables.

The smart_curmonth_downs_raw table is the raw download information (download stats), the karen table adds unique user information, and the smart_items table adds unique items (download) info.  They are all important.  If a user made a download but is knocked off the karen table I would like to see NULLs for the user info and if there is more than one item in smart_items that has the same name then I would like to see just the item with the highest ID.

Comment: How would you define the **last** itemtitle that is in smart_items? For instance, is there a column with a datetime value that you want the most recent, or an incremented value that you want the largest? (You should share the smart_items table schema in your question)

Comment: @AgRizzo - Sorry should have mentioned that.  The smart_items table is actually the only table that has a proper key.  So it would be the highest "id" field in the table.  When I get the report as "smart_curmonth_downs_raw" they only have the itemtitle, not the id... don't get me started.  I can definitely rant about one of the worst corporate CMSs I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like relationship between `smart_curmonth_downs_raw` and `ldap_karen` is optional, which means you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` which all the rows in the first table, and, if the right table does not exists, use NULL as the right table's column values.

In terms of the last item in the smart_items table, you could use this query.

```
SELECT title, MAX(id) AS max_id
FROM smart_items
GROUP BY title;
```

Combining that query with the other logic, try this query as a solution.

```
SELECT COALESCE(ldap_karen.uid, 'Unknown') AS uid,
       COALESCE(ldap_karen.supemail, 'Unknown') AS supemail,
       COALESCE(ldap_karen.regionname, 'Unknown') AS regionname,
       smart_curmonth_downs_raw.username,
       smart_curmonth_downs_raw.email,
       smart_curmonth_downs_raw.publisher,
       smart_curmonth_downs_raw.itemtitle,
       smart_items.`Owner`
FROM smart_curmonth_downs_raw
INNER JOIN (SELECT title, MAX(id) AS max_id
            FROM smart_items
            GROUP BY title) AS most_recent
  ON smart_curmonth_downs_raw.itemtitle = most_recent.Title;      
INNER JOIN smart_items 
  ON most_recent.max_id = smart_items.id
LEFT JOIN ldap_karen 
  ON smart_curmonth_downs_raw.username = ldap_karen.uid;
```

Comment: the smart_curmonth_downs_raw table is the raw download information (download stats), the karen table adds unique user information, and the smart_items table adds unique items (download) info.  They are all important.  Your query has some issues but I will see if I can work it out at all.